# Can Active Directory-based DNS servers return results for arbitrary domain names?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Our internal DNS queries go through Active Directory. We are hosting a site that is not in our domain, but internal users need to get the internal IP address for routing.

How do I configure Active Directory to return A records for a few arbitrary domain names, not just those in our own domain?

Answer (score 4):

You can create any zone you want in your AD DNS servers; nothing prevents you from defining a zone with the same name as a real, public Internet DNS zone.

If you do that, any user querying your DNS servers (that's all domain users, usually) will get the answers *you* defined instead of the real ones.

Comment: +1, this is called split horizon DNS.  Just make sure that you include *all* the records in the real zone or you'll find your mail bouncing (i.e. if you miss the MX records).

Comment: Rather than adding the entire "whateverdomain.com" zone and adding records within it, you may want to just add "host.whateverdomain.com" as a zone and create an "@" record (blank hostname) with the internal address, such that the remainder of the "whateverdomain.com" zone resolves from the Internet DNS.

Comment: @Evan: it's likely he doesn't have a choice, unless he can just do www.whateverdomain.com with an "@" record and not include the whateverdomain.com zone in AD.

Comment: @gravyface: I think we're saying the same thing. I create zones w/ only "@" records in them on Microsoft DNS servers fairly frequently just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making separate DNS Zones? Take a look at [this](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/DNS_Stub_Zones.html)

Which version of AD?